# How to map JSON in a Java object

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I'm trying to transform this JSON in a Java object. But I'm struggling with this conversion.

```
{
    "id": "c01cede4-cd45-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003",
    "publisherId": "nintendo",
    "name": "Mario",
    "timePlayed": {
        "2023-05-01": 10,
        "2023-05-02": 2,
        "2023-05-03": 3,
        "2023-05-04": 4
    }
}
```

First, I created a class named `GameData` and I was able to save the first 3 parameters with no problem at all.
My difficult is with parameter `timePlayed`. I tried to create another class named `TimePlayed`, using the annotation Entity–relationship model but I have no success with that. Also, I tried to use a `Map` instead using the object `TimePlayed` but it did not work as well.
As you can see, inside the `timePlayed` is a date and an integer.
This is the code that I have while writing this question:

Class `GameData`:

```
@Table(name = "GAME_DATA")
@Entity
@Data
public class GameData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String gameDataId;

    private String publisherId;
    private String name;

    private Map<Date, String> timePlayed;


}
```

Class `TimePlayed`

```
@Table(name = "TIME_PLAYED")
@Data
@Entity
public class TimePlayed {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private Map<String, Integer> playedDateAndTime;

}
```

My guess that using a second class is not the best approach but this what I was capable to do so far and, of course, is not working at all.
I got a some errors like:

- Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing hibernate JPA
- 'Basic' attribute type should not be a map

Comment: "I have no success with that" and "it did not work as well" are not very useful problem descriptions. Can you be more specific?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to put the errors that I got. I'm adding then right now.

Comment: I guess the slogan is misleading, since your JSON data maps perfectly (excett for the attribute names) to your GameData class. If this is a JPA problem, you probably need a @OneToMany association on `timePlayed`, and you should not need to declare that class, since the association table woud be generated for you.

Comment: Use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`. Are you using Jackson? Use jacksone-modules-java8 and add the Jackdon time module to your mapper. Disable the write dates as timestamps feature. Search for the details, they have been given a couple of times in Stack Overflow and elsewhere already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem using this the class this way:

```
@Table(name = "GAME")
@Entity
@Data
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String gameDataId;

    private String publisherId;
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "date")
    @Column(name = "time_played")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/mm/dd")
    private Map<LocalDate, Integer> timePlayed;

}
```

This way, I could save and show the JSON the way I need.

Answer (score 1):

Usually converting to map is a very non-trivial task, I would suggest changing the structure of the json itself, if this is possible, for example, to this:

```json
{
    "id": "c01cede4-cd45-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003",
    "publisherId": "nintendo",
    "name": "Mario",
    "timePlayed": [
      {
        "date":"2023-05-01",
        "time": 10
      },
      {
        "date":"2023-05-02",
        "time": 2
      },
      {
        "date":"2023-05-03",
        "time": 3
      },
      {
        "date":"2023-05-04",
        "time": 4
      },
    ]
}
```

This will allow you to bring your classes to this form:

```java
public class GameData{
    public String id;
    public String publisherId;
    public String name;
    public List<TimePlayed> timePlayed;
}

public class TimePlayed{
    public LocalDate date;
    public inttime;
}
```

As for your mistakes, it’s hard to say without details, but most likely this is due to the fact that the child entity needs to be preserved to the same extent as the parent or use cascade types. [JPA Cascade Types / Baeldang](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)